# windows phone 8.1 how to make a determinate circle progressbar

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

In Windows Phone 8.1, how can I modify the progressbar like the circle below? The ring should be determinate.

[image: circle progressbar]

Comment: possible duplicate of [WPF Radial Progressbar/Meter (i.e. Battery Meter)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23046565/wpf-radial-progressbar-meter-i-e-battery-meter)

Comment: No, the other answer did not work, at least for me. Probably it is valid for WPF.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `ProgressRing`. Take a look at [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/2d2d83/progress-bar-and-progress-ring-in-windows-phone-8-1/).

```
<ProgressRing x:Name="myProgressRing" IsActive="True" Height="90" Width="90" />
```

If you want to make it determinate look at [this article](http://blog.rectorsquid.com/circular-determinate-progress-bar-in-c-for-windows-store/).

Comment: That's not I want since it is indeterminate. My progresbar should be determinate. @DavidLeither

Comment: added a link to answer.